# Inheriting from generic base class crashes LLVM

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In swift3, inheriting from a `generic` base class causes LLVM to crash, the same code snippet works if the base class is not a `generic` class or when a default constructor is introduced in the child class, wondering what is causing the LLVM to crash

```
class Base<T> {
    let name: String?

    init(name: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        print("Super")
    }
}

class Child : Base<String> {
}

var child = Child()
```

Comment: This seems like a special case of the bug reported in [this resolved bug report (SR-416)](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-416). Here with the special condition that you use a default value for a parameter in the superclass initializer, and attempt to call the inherited initializer omitting this argument (hence making use of the default value) for the derived class. E.g. `var child = Child(name: "foo")` (now) works as it should. You might want to flag a bug report for this and link to the related (resolved) report above.